# SQL: Join condition is eliminating query result to zero rows. a non-empty result set is required

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT tro.order_id,
       tro.order_code,
       tol.location,
       tos.token as transport_order_status          

  FROM transport_order tro

  JOIN transport_order_location tol
    ON tol.location_id = tro.location_id

  JOIN transport_order_status tos
    ON tos.status_id = tro.status_id
   AND tos.token = 'finished';
```

> `tos.token` is a unique varchar value.

the above SQL statement is joining tables: `transport_order`, `transport_order_location` and `transport_order_status`.

Supposing that we have no `finished` orders yet, then the query will return no rows.

It is requested that in such case we want to display the complete data of the transport_order with some alternative text in the status (something like `not_finished`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a left join and a coalesce

```
SELECT tro.order_id,
       tro.order_code,
       tol.location,
       COALESCE(tos.token, 'Not Finished') AS transport_order_status          

  FROM transport_order tro

  INNER JOIN transport_order_location tol
    ON tol.location_id = tro.location_id

  LEFT JOIN transport_order_status tos
    ON tos.status_id = tro.status_id
   AND tos.token = 'finished';
```